# What is the linguistic purpose of 'one' as an adjective preceding a noun?

Tags: word-usage

For example, I have heard people say 'remember when we saw that **one** guy?', or 'my **one** exam just got postponed'. Is it a form of hedging?

Comment: In both your examples, the meaning I can attribute is that there was only one guy there, and I have only one exam, and the speaker is emphasising the uniqueness.

Comment: Note that "proceding" is not a word. You can have  "preceding" or "proceeding". I assume you mean the former. I've edited the title.

Answer (score 1):

> 'remember when we saw that one guy?'

I interpret this as meaning "unique". For example, suppose we attended an entertainment event and there were ten players and one of them was wearing a bear's head. Later we might say, "Remember when we saw that one guy - the one with the bear's head?"

> 'my one exam just got postponed'

I interpret this as meaning "one-and-only". I had only one exam and it was postponed.

Answer (score 0):

It is a determinar used to add emphasis:

> ***[One](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/one)*** can be used instead of 'a' to emphasize the following noun.
> [emphasis]

> *There is one thing I would like to know–What is it about Tim that you find so irresistible?
> One person I hate is Russ.*

(Collins Dictionary)

Comment: But that meaning doesn't fit either of the OP's examples.

Comment: @ColinFine - it is an extension of that usage.

Comment: Maybe. But unlike your example, it doesn't make sense in the OP's examples **unless** it has the sense of uniqueness. Your example does not have that sense at all.